# React, trying to use setState only once

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state, react-state-management

Is there any other good way to use setState() only once?

```
onSearchSubmit = async input => {
    const response = await weather.get('/weather', {
      params: {
        q: this.state.city || input,
      },
    });

    this.setState({ weather: response.data, input: '', city: '' });
  };
```

And then in render function:

```
this.state.city ? this.onSearchSubmit() : this.onSearchSubmit
```

Comment: In render function? You should not trigger a `setState` inside the render function. It will end up in an endless loop. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please state your objective more clearly